# dup() creating file but not printing to it

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a shell in c++. It creates a child process which executes a command and pipes the response back to the parent. I want to specify if the second argument of a command is `-o` then I would like to redirect the output of the command to a file. (output.txt).I used `dup()` to redirect output to my file. However, when I run the program and enter for example `wc -o fileName` the program creates the file output.txt but does not write to it when I specify to print the result of my child process.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <vector>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(){
    // array of file descriptors for parent and child
    int filedes[2];
    char foo[4096];
    char** argv;
    std::cout << "$$-> ";
    char command[128];
    std::cin.getline(command, 128);
    if(strlen(command) != 0) {
      std::vector<char *> args;
      char *prog = strtok(command, " ");
      char *tmp = prog;
      while(tmp != NULL) {
        args.push_back(tmp);
        tmp = strtok(NULL, " ");
      }
      argv = new char *[args.size() + 1];
      for (int k = 0; k < args.size(); k++) {
        argv[k] = args[k];
      }
      argv[args.size()] = NULL;
     }
     char* newargc = argv[0];
     char *newargv[] = {newargc,argv[2],NULL};
     if(pipe(filedes) < 0){
       std::cout << "There was an error creating the pipe";
     }
     int pid = fork();
     if(pid == 0){
       // writing to the pipe
       // close read end of pipe
       close(filedes[0]);
       close(STDOUT_FILENO);
       dup(filedes[1]);
       if(strcmp(argv[1],(char*)"-o") == 0 ||strcmp(argv[1], (char*) "-b") == 0){
         execvp(newargv[0], newargv);
       }
       else{
         execvp(argv[0],argv);
       }
    }
    else if (pid > 0) {
      std::cout << "This is the parent process\n";
      while(wait(NULL) > 0);
      close(filedes[1]);
      int output_fd = open("output.txt", O_CREAT, O_TRUNC, O_RDWR);
      read(filedes[0], foo, sizeof(foo));
      if(strcmp(argv[1],(char*)"-o") == 0){
        close(STDOUT_FILENO);
        dup(output_fd);
        write(output_fd, foo, sizeof(foo));
      }
      else if(strcmp(argv[1], (char*) "-b") == 0){
        int stdoutHolder = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(STDOUT_FILENO);
        dup(output_fd);
        std::cout<< foo;
        dup2(stdoutHolder, 1);
      }


        std::cout << foo;
    }
    //pid is less than 0 if error
    else{
      std::cout << "There is an error.";
    }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't tag C++ questions as C. Since you're using C++, use `std::string` *whenever possible*. This code is rife with C buffer overflow bugs. You should also steer towards `std::vector` instead of `new[]`.

Comment: `open("output.txt", O_CREAT, O_TRUNC, O_RDWR)`. You should combine the `O_` flags with `|` in the 2nd argument, not pass them as the 2nd, 3rd and 4th argument. The 3rd argument should be a *mode* for the newly open file if you're using `O_CREAT`.

Comment: Why are you casting things like `"-o"` as `char*`? It's `const char*` and should be left as-is. Even better, compare `std::string` to that with a simple `==`.

Comment: And you're ignoring the return values of all those functions. For instance, you're just writing `sizeof(foo)` bytes, even if you don't know that the previous `read` got that much in the `foo` buffer. Start with checking for error ALL those calls (read, write, open, dup, dup2, etc).